# how to hide 2^12 binary bit in RGB layer

Tags: java, bufferedimage, steganography

i want to hide 2^12 binary bit into a RGB layer. Example 000011010000 this value i want to hide in RGB layer. the 2^12 bit must devide into 3 layer like 0000 hide in R layer 1101 in G layer and 0000 in B layer. anyone know how to do this in java..

Answer (score 1):

The term for what you're trying to do is "digital steganography", specifically digital image steganography.  Search for steganography and java and you'll find several examples, including stuff like this: http://www.stratos.me/2008/04/steganography-and-bitmap-files-for-hardcores-or-masochists/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have an original image in non-compressed form (e.g., bitmap, PNG) and you want to create a modified image that can be used in conjunction with the original image to extract the hidden data. If so, I think hiding 12 bits of data into one pixel would probably be too noticeable. Perhaps three bits of data per pixel would work best, assuming each pixel takes up 3n bytes. Then you could flip the least significant bit iff the bit you are hiding is a 1. I glanced at @CaptainAwesomePants's reference, and it seems along the same lines as this suggestion, but with more technical detail and examples. (I gave his/her answer +1.)